# Translation of 同じで in 同じで分かり合ってる

Tags: translation, adverbs, particle-で

同じで分かり合ってる is a sentence in a lyrics of this song https://utaten.com/lyric/jb81104032/

Some sources translate this as “We understand each other the same”

Some as “We understand each other because we are the same”

Which one is correct ?

In my opinion I think 2nd sentence is correct. Because I think that it has to be 同じく to form 1st sentence.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Song lyrics has many ambiguous lines somewhat intensionally. So I think the both could be right. However, let me add a 3rd interpretation on this.

After checking the whole lyrics I have just thought a different meaning. That is like this.

> いつだって同じで
>
> You always do like that.
>
> 分かり合ってる？・・とんだ勘違いだよ
>
> What a misunderstanding that you and me understand each other!!

I separated the line to 2 parts as above. It's possible because the first 2 lines of this lyrics sound like blaming someone. So it makes sense "You always do like that" as a criticizing comment.

"いつも同じ" (always the same) is common phrase and it often contains "unsatisfied" or "boring" meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask one more question if you don't mind. 同じで分かり合ってる. Can this 同じ+で function as adverb here ( understand "the same"). I just only know that I have to use 同じく as an adverb to mean "the same".

Comment: Yes!! 同じ+で is used like adverb and the meaning is "the same" or "similarly". 同じく and 同じで is very close each other. My suggestion of the interpretation was "(you) always the same" => "you won't change".

Comment: Honestly thank you for clear and great answers. I’d been wondering for years. Thank you very much sir !